# Printing images as bakgrounds from HTML View in PDF

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm struggling very hard to be able to print a simple certificate template, my current problems are:

1. I need to set two images for background, front page and backpage. Currently I set them up using some css positioning through  tags.
2. When I set all the layout, they are fine in the HTML view, however, once I try yo print from browser, or from a custom plugin (rotativa wkhtmlpdf), the layout get messed up and all formatting is gone.

Below is the code:
PS. @img_frente and @img_verso are base64 strings for the images as backgrounds.

```css
 @@font-face {
            font-family: fonteMaior;
            src: url("../../Content/fonts/DINNextLTPro-Condensed.otf")
        }
/*        @@font-face {
            font-family: fonteMenor;
            src: url("../../Content/fonts/")
        }*/
        html {
            margin: 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0 0;
            font-family: fonteMaior;
            font-size: 28px;
            color: #464646;
        }

        .line {
            height: 20px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1 !important;
            position: center;
        }

        * {
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .mainText {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .qrcode {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 72px;
            left: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #D1D1D1 !important;
        }

        .registro {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 120px;
            left: 265px;
        }

        .instrutor {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 120px;
            left: 812px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        .verso {
            position: relative;

        }
        .conteudos {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 430px;
            left: 135px;
        }

        @@media screen, print {
            html, body, #xxl {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                font-family:fonteMaior;
                font-size:28;
            }

            #printable {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            img{
                display:inline;
            }
                #printable ~ * {
                    display: none;
                    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
                }
        }
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/library/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"href="~/Content/css/library/fontawesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/md-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/style.css">
        <script>
            window.load = function () {
                window.status = 'render-pdf';
            };
        </script>
        <style>
    
            CSS is above
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frenteCert" class="frente container">
            <img src=@img_frente alt="imagem frente" />
            <div class="mainText text-justify" style="font-family:fonteMaior;">
                <span class="">
                    @ViewBag.nomeProfessor, confere a <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">@ViewBag.nomeAluno</b> o presente certificado, referente à sua participação no curso <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">@ViewBag.nomeCurso</b>,
                    concluído em @ViewBag.dataCertificado @*@ViewBag.dataConclusao*@ , com carga horária de @ViewBag.cargaHoraria horas.
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="qrCode" class="qrcode">
                <img src="@ViewBag.QRCodeImage" alt="" style="height:150px;width:150px" />
            </div>
            <div id="dataEmissao" class="registro">
                <p style="font-size:24px; font-family:fonteMaior;">Curitiba, 21 de Maio de 2021.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="instrutor" class="instrutor">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <p class="text-center" style="text-align:center; font-size: 24px; font-family:fonteMaior;">INSTRUTOR</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="versoCert" class="verso container">
            <img src=@img_verso alt="imagem verso" />
            <div id="colunas" class="conteudos">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.conteudos)
                {
                    <p>@item.conteudo</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller:
This is only the part where I call the PDF generator, which is working but idk how to configure better.

```
var viewPdf = new PartialViewAsPdf
{
    ViewName = "_GeraCertificado",
    RotativaOptions = { PageOrientation = Rotativa.Core.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                        PageSize = Rotativa.Core.Options.Size.A4 },
    FileName = "certificado.pdf",
    Model = tbl_aluno_curso
};

if (isPdf != null && isPdf == true)
{
    return viewPdf;
}
```

Here is a sample image of the current output in html

[Output in PDF - front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6LGG.png)

[Output in PDF- back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMSVc.png)

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXhp2.png)

[Back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE7PG.png)

Comment: Hi @CaioVC, have you tried using a simple view with a layout, adding CSS and scripts through BundleConfig and calling ViewAsPdf method? Which Rotativa version are you using? Rotativa Options can be set simplier in your case, just by using: `return new PartialViewAsPdf
        {
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            FileName = "certificado.pdf",
            Model = new tbl_aluno_curso()
        };`

Comment: About the CCS you specify first, where is it placed? On style.css file refererenced as a link or between the style tags in the view? If it's possible, I would be very useful if you could provide an HTML sample that works outside your environment (tried to use cdnjs links for bootstrap, jquery and plugins, but seems that some CSS are still missed, and/or the versions do not match)? Obrigado.

Comment: Hello Dave!! Thank you very much for your feedback, it turns out that i managed to get it done by changing layout style to absolute/relative positioning, instead of using row and cols, also i reverted the background to be div background, so i configured background-image in css to get my background! Thank you very much for rotativa configs heheh

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to hear it's working! Remember that you could post your own answer, and mark it as solution, if you wish to share the adquired knowledge with the community ;)

Comment: Hey Dave, answer shared. Thank you very much friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to a solution, treating div structure as parent/child with a master container on each block of the certificate, then aligned them with relative/absolute positioning.
Full code below:

PS. I removed useless scripts and the viewbags at src in img tags and vars are just base64 strings. I hope this can help people out!

```
                   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/library/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/library/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/library/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/md-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="~/Content/css/style.css">

        <style>
    
            @@font-face {
                font-family: fonteMaior;
                src: url("../../Content/fonts/DINNextLTPro-Condensed.otf")
            }
    
            * {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                page-break-inside: avoid !important;
            }
    
            html {
                margin: 0 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
    
            body {
                margin: 0 0;
                font-family: fonteMaior !important;
                font-size: 28px;
                color: #464646;
                padding: 0;
            }
    
            .line {
                height: 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1 !important;
                position: center;
            }
    
            .container {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
            }
    
            .mainText {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
    
            .qrcode {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 72px;
                left: 95px;
                border: 1px solid #D1D1D1 !important;
            }
    
            .registro {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 120px;
                left: 265px;
            }
    
            .instrutor {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 120px;
                left: 775px;
                width: 300px;
            }
    
            #assinatura {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 99;
                bottom: 35px;
                left: 65px;
                max-width: 280px;
                max-height: 110px;
                width: auto !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }
    
            .frente {
                background-image: url( @img_frente ) !important;
                background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                background-position: top !important;
                background-size: contain !important;
                display: block !important;
                width: 1170px !important;
                height: 825px !important;
            }
            .verso {
                background-image: url( @img_verso ) !important;
                background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                background-position: top !important;
                background-size: contain !important;
                display: block !important;
                width: 1170px !important;
                height: 825px !important;
            }
    
            .conteudos {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 140px;
                left: 135px;
                display: inline-flex;
                flex-flow: column wrap;
                align-content: flex-start;
                height: 530px;
    /*            border: 1px solid blue !important;*/
            }
            .listConteudos{
    
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: contents;
                float: left;
                flex-flow: column wrap;
                align-content: flex-start;
            }
    
            
            @@media screen, print {
                html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    border: 0;
                    font-family: fonteMaior !important;
                    font-size:28px;
                }
                .certContainer{
    
                }
                #printable {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    border: 0;
                    font-size: 14px;
                }
    
                img{
                    display:inline;
                }
                    #printable ~ * {
                        display: none;
                        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
                    }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frenteCert" class="frente container">
            @*<img src=@img_frente alt="imagem frente" />*@
            <div class="mainText text-justify" style="font-family:fonteMaior;">
                <span class="">
                    @ViewBag.nomeProfessor, confere a <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">@ViewBag.nomeAluno</b> o presente certificado, referente à sua participação no curso <b style="text-transform: uppercase;">@ViewBag.nomeCurso</b>,
                    concluído em @ViewBag.dataConclusao, com carga horária de @ViewBag.cargaHoraria horas.
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="qrCode" class="qrcode">
                <img src="@ViewBag.QRCodeImage" alt="" style="height:150px;width:150px" />
            </div>
            <div id="dataEmissao" class="registro">
                @if (ViewBag.cidade != null && ViewBag.estado != null)
                {
                    <p style="font-size:24px; font-family:fonteMaior;">@ViewBag.cidade - @ViewBag.estado, @ViewBag.dataCertificado.</p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p style="font-size:24px; font-family:fonteMaior;">CIDADE - UF, @ViewBag.dataCertificado.</p>
                }        </div>
            <div id="instrutor" class="instrutor">
                @if (ViewBag.assinatura != null)
                {
                    <img id="assinatura" src=@ViewBag.assinatura alt="" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <img id="assinatura" src=@signature alt="" style="height:75px;width:280px" />
                }
    
                <div class="line"></div>
                <p class="text-center" style="text-align:center; font-size: 24px; font-family:fonteMaior;">INSTRUTOR</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="versoCert" class="verso container" style="text-align:unset !important">
            @*<img src=@img_verso alt="imagem verso" />*@
            <div id="colunas" class="conteudos" style="width: 200px !important">
                <ul class="listConteudos">
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.conteudos)
                    {
                        <li style="font-family:fonteMaior; font-size: 18px !important; margin-right: 15px !important;">@item.conteudo</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```